# How to figure out the type of _id after it sent to the client?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have app running node.js with mongodb. When I query data in the Chrome debugger I can see if _id field is ObjectId, or if it's just a string.

But when data is sent to the client, the result json is always string. Therefore, if I send the document back to update on the server side it will be string unless I transform it into ObjectId. So the question is how I can figure out if I should transform this string into ObjectId, or leave it as a string?

Or, maybe there is a way to keep _id as kind of ObjectId when the object is sent to the client?

NB I don't have any mongoose models, I work with raw data using Node.js MongoDB driver.

Comment: How are you updating if you don't have models in your server side?

Comment: @juliansalas I update data using mongodb driver for Node.js. Examples here http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/tutorials/crud/

Comment: If you're not using Mongoose, then your server-side code needs to perform validation and casting as necessary based on whatever structure you want to enforce.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know the type of the field _id in the client side, a simple workaround should be to include a idType type field like this:

```
{
    "_id": "1234",
    "idType": "string",
    ...
}
```

This way you can easily check this field on your client and guess the type.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about something like that but it's not possible. The point is we don't work with our data, it's for our clients that work with their own data, so we can' t litter their data.

Comment: I don't understand your scenario, but I can answer you that there is no way to keep the type of the field _id using json.

Comment: I actually found the solution. On the server side I determine the type (if it's ObjectId or not, it's easy), then if yes, transform to string representation like "ObjectId('somelongnumber')" and send to the client. And back, when data is coming from the client I do the opposite transform.